# Evaluate regular expression in Shell script

Tags: shell

I'm writing a Shell script that runs several times a program measuring the execution time.

The problem is that, while in the terminal I can write

`java -jar MyProgram.jar ../../A_Directory/**/*.java`

in the script, if I write this

```
DIR_FILE=$1
RESULT_FILE=`pwd`'/results/'$2
DIR_FILE=$DIR_FILE/**/*.java

MYPROGRAM="java -jar ../IntraJ.jar "

for a in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
 $MYPROGRAM $DIR_FILE
done
```

an error is generated by MyProgram since `$DIR_FILE` is not evaluated but is passed to MyProgram as a string.

How can I evaluate it?

Comment: I tried a simplified similar bash script, and it worked.

Comment: Always start by running your script through shellcheck and fixing issues it points out.